# Update canvas style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

So I have some basic canvas and an`<input type="color">`and I want to change the color of a certain shape `on change` of the color.

Here is my code

```
var colorRect = '#000';

var ball = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = ball.getContext("2d");
var ctx1 = ball.getContext("2d");
ctx1.fillStyle = colorRect;
ctx1.fillRect(0,0,200,200);
ctx1.save();

//Left eye
ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
ctx.fillRect(50,80,10,10);

//Right eye
ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
ctx.fillRect(150,80,10,10);

//Nose
ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
ctx.fillRect(100,110,10,20);

//Mouth

ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fillRect(60,150,100,10);

$('#favcolor').on('change',function(){
  colorRect = $(this).val();
  ctx1.fillStyle = $(this).val();
  ctx1.fillRect(0,0,200,200);
});
```

Here you can see it live: http://jsbin.com/inewum/1 the problem is that I think it overwrites everything, because I can't see the eyes and mouth anymore...I just want to update the style that's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to redraw it. Create your draw routine and color state variables. When you change something just redraw it with the new colors.

You are just changing context fill style and draw a rectangle on it. That is why the eyes and mouth disappear.

Change to this and see the [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/inewum/2/edit):

```
$(function () {

    draw();
    $('#favcolor').on('change', function () {
        colorRect = $(this).val();
        draw();
    });

});

var colorRect = '#000';

function draw() {

    var ball = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = ball.getContext("2d");
    var ctx1 = ball.getContext("2d");
    ctx1.fillStyle = colorRect;
    ctx1.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
    ctx1.save();

    //Left eye
    ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
    ctx.fillRect(50, 80, 10, 10);

    //Right eye
    ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
    ctx.fillRect(150, 80, 10, 10);

    //Nose
    ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
    ctx.fillRect(100, 110, 10, 20);

    //Mouth

    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fillRect(60, 150, 100, 10);
}
```

Comment: Oh great thanks, So it doesn't have an event like update and the just push it, you kinda have to re-draw everything just to update a certain element, got it! I will accept it asap

Comment: @Uffo Do you have to do it this way? There are plenty of good canvas engines/frameworks that take care of performance issues and can accelerate development process. First get used and understand how canvas work and then use available tools out there. Good luck

Comment: You should also probably clear the canvas context in this case.

Answer (score 1):

All HTML5 canvas figures (rectangles, circles, lines etc.) are not a substantive objects, and you can't manipulate with them such as with JavaScript DOM objects. For that reason you have to redraw the whole canvas image to change the options for separate elements.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps SVG is more what you need, you can treat the SVG elements just like you would any old HTML.

Here is your example done with SVG http://jsbin.com/inewum/15/edit

The script can be reduced to:

```
$('#favcolor').on('change',function(){
    $('.face').css({
      'fill': $(this).val()
    });
});
```

And the canvas can be replaced with:

```
<svg height=200 width=200 viewBox='0 0 200 200'>
   <rect width=200 height=200 class="face" />
   <!-- left eye -->
   <rect x=50 y=80 width=10 height=10 fill="white"/>
   <!-- right eye -->
   <rect x=150 y=80 width=10 height=10 fill="white"/>
   <!-- nose -->
   <rect x=100 y=110 width=10 height=20 fill="white"/>
   <!-- mouth -->
   <rect x=60 y=150 width=100 height=10 fill="red"/>
</svg>
```